# when I press the button the app didnt work and no error send

Tags: android

I have to write an app which can ping  the given URL.
I just write a simple app with a class and a layout. But it did not work.
when i write the url and press the button the app crash

my class
    package com.example.administrator.saraping;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText editText;
private String uRL;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private Process process;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editTextt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
     uRL = editText.getText().toString();
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            ping(uRL);
        }
    };
}

public void ping(String url) {
   String str = "";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + url);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((i = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        bufferedReader.close();

        str = output.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TextView ping = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ping);
    ping.setText(str);
}
}
```

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView android:text="@string/Insert"
            android:textSize="34dp"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="316dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_weight="0.16" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:id=@+id/button" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="34dp"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ping" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you expect people to help you when you **don't tell them what the error/behavior is**?

Comment: That means it's crashing.  Post the stack trace (error logs) from the crash.

Comment: You don't know how to find it but you try to develop complicated app? start with "hello world" first.

Comment: you dont used button id for onclick or android:onClick in xml.we cant tell exactly what causing the error.Because still you don't posted Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working, but there were many small things wrong with it.

Main issues:

- The Activity needs to be public
- The network operation needs to be in a background thread, I used an AsyncTask.
- It wasn't clear how you had your button click event set up, I just set it up in the Java code.
- The text from the URL EditText wasn't getting captured when the button was clicked, so the uRL String was always empty.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private String uRL;
    //private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    //private InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    //private Process process;
    private Button button;
    private TextView ping; //added

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        ping = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ping); //added
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //added

        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                uRL = editText.getText().toString();

                new PingAsync().execute(uRL);
                //ping(uRL);
            }
        });
    }

    class PingAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = ping(params[0]);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null){
                ping.setText(result);
            }
        }
    }

    //String return value
    public String ping(String url) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + url);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            Log.d("ping", "do ping: " + url);
            int i;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((i = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                output.append(buffer, 0, i);
            bufferedReader.close();

            str = output.toString();
            Log.d("ping", "ping result:: " + str);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return str; //added
    }
}
```

Also here is an improved layout with one nested LinearLayout for the top row, left margins, and better font sizes (also you should use sp for font sizes).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView android:text="insert"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_weight="0.16" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="submit"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ping" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @SARA I just updated the answer with a better layout.

Comment: I have a question can you please tell me your android version

Comment: @sara I'm using 4.4.4

Comment: @sara one more thing, make sure to learn how to get and read logs before you post your next question!!! The first reason is that you are basically coding blind if you can't read your own logs.  Second, if you can't figure something out on your own even after studying the logs, and need to post a question on SO, and it's a crashing issue, you absolutely need to include logs, otherwise people will down vote your question.

Comment: thank you It's just 5 days that I start android and i never have programming befor that's why i don't know alotof things if you can help me and say something that good for me say please

Comment: Could you give me a way to connect because hear could not speak much

Comment: @SARA Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse?  Either way, the logs should show up in the IDE when you run your project.  Search the web, there are plenty of tutorials on how to read Android logs!

Comment: Android studio yeah i saw the log but i can't understand which line is important

Comment: @SARA When you're running from Android Studio in debug mode, and a crash occurs, the log will stop and the error will be shown. Make sure that you're filtering the logs on your app's logs, so you don't get the entire system logs.